# forEach doesn't iterate all collection in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t

I need to compare two collections of objects from mongo db.
My shell script looks like this:

```
//Both arrays have 367 pretty big objects.
var list1 = db.collection1.find({..condition..}).toArray(); 
var list2 = db.collection2.find({..condition..}).toArray();

function compare(left, right){
   var l = left.data.NP;
   var r = right.data.NP;
   if(JSON.stringify(l) === JSON.stringify(r)){
      return 'Equal';
   } else {
      return 'Not equal';
   }
}

list1.forEach(function(item, index){
   print(index, compare(item,list2[index]));
})
```

I execute this script in the Robomongo.
But i have a problem. At the result only 8 items from 367 was printed. Robomongo didn't show any error messages.
When i used

```
print(item);
```

inside foreach, all worked fine and all 367 objects was printed. Also i tried to use Deep Diff library for objects comparison but got same result - only 12 items from 367 was printed.

I think the problem in the memory consumption, but i don't know how to handle it, and why Robomongo doesn't print any errors.

I tried to iterate only cursors but it didn't help.

Why foreach could iterate not all items and how to fix it ?

**[UPDATE 1]**
After some time of the investigation i mentioned that if i run script in just opened tab in Robomongo it prints 102 elements, but when i run it again in the same tab it prints only 12.

**[UPDATE 2]**
I tried to run script using native mongo shell mongo.exe and got 100 from 367 elements printed, without errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Updated]**

It might be related to the timeout. Robomongo has 15 seconds default timeout which is in the config file and it can be changed. This might help:

**[Update-1]**
Starting from version Robo 3T - 1.1 (formerly Robomongo), the shell timeout is configurable on UI and also there is a fix to prevent this issue happening. See
http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-is-robo-3t/#4a. So no need to change config file as explained below for older versions.

**Workaround solution for earlier versions than 1.1:**

> Make sure Robomongo is closed. Open robomongo.json configuration file.
>
> [Update]: Adding link to [Robomongo-Config-File-Guide](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/wiki/Robomongo-Config-File-Guide) for newer versions.
>
> ```
> Windows
>   0.9.x
>   C:\Users\<user>\.config\robomongo\0.9\robomongo.json
>   0.8.x
>   C:\Users\<user>\.config\robomongo\robomongo.json   
> MAC
>     0.9.x
>     /Users/<user>/.config/robomongo/0.9/robomongo.json
>     0.8.x
>    /Users/<user>/.config/robomongo/robomongo.json     
> Linux
>     0.9.x
>     /home/<user>/.config/robomongo/0.9/robomongo.json
>     0.8.x
>     /home/<user>/.config/robomongo/robomongo.json
> ```
>
> 1. Change "shellTimeoutSec" attribute value to higher number in seconds. (i.e. "shellTimeoutSec" : 60)
> 2. Save config file and re-launch Robomongo app.
> 3. Run necessary script. If script isn't executed entirely, try to increase shellTimeoutSec value.

Reference:
https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/1106#issuecomment-230258348