# Why the robomongo close when found more than 100 thousand registers?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

code: `db.getCollection('tcc').find({"keys.year":1990})`

I know that have more than  100 thousand documents

When I execute this code, my robomongo close

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the contributors of Robomongo. Do you mean Robomongo crashes by "my robomongo close"? If it is a crash,  I suggest you should report this problem by creating a ticket on Robomongo github. If it is not a crash, please give more information about the problem.

Also, my answer for this question, might also worth to try: 
[forEach doesn't iterate all collection in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838221/foreach-doesnt-iterate-all-collection-in-mongodb/39914873#39914873)

Comment: I need to iterate through the collection in MongoDB, because I'm doing a database comparison.